# Find joint distribution from transformation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, transformation, bivariate-distributions

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1]$.

Let $$ X_1 = \sqrt{-2\log(U_1)} \cos(2 \pi U_2), $$ and

$$ X_2 = \sqrt{-2\log(U_1)} \sin(2 \pi U_2) $$

Find the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I can see that $X_1^2 + X_2^2 = -2log(U_1)$ and $\frac{X_2}{X_1} = \tan(2 \pi U_2) $ but I don't know how to further manipulate the transformation to get the joint distribution.

Comment: edited! Sorry it's just a typo previously

Comment: Hint: $X_1^2+X_2^2$ looks like the square of a radius from the origin while $\tan^{-1}(\frac {X_2}{X_1})$ looks like an angle

Comment: So the angle looks uniformly distributed (rotational symmetry) and perhaps (without checking) you have something like $P(R \le r) = P(R^2 \le r^2) $ $= P(-2\log(U_1) \le r^2$ $= P(\log(U_1) \ge -\frac{r^2}{2}$ $= P(U_1 \ge e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}})$   $= 1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$ which is starting to look a little like something else familiar